# How to access request.user with AbstractUser class

Tags: python-3.x, django, request, abstractuser

I am trying to create an order object and assign the order's customer field (which is a foreign key for User) to the current user. Even though it passes the if statement and it can authenticate the request.user, it assigns customer as a blank value.

When I print customer it prints a blank line, however when I print customer.id, it prints the ID of the customer. This happens in all views in the project so its a global issue

I belive this has something to do with the fact that my user class is inheriting from AbstractUser

**utils.py**

```
def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print('This will print')
        customer = request.user
        print(customer) #This will print as a blank line
        print(customer.id) #This will print the request.user.id
        print(customer.username) #This will print the request.user.username
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
   author = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'main.User'
```

The database is updated with the user as blank too. I feel like this may be an easy one but I can't figure it out! Thanks.

Comment: Have you implemented `__str__` or `__repr__` on your custom user class? Make sure to return a proper string representation there (you might be returning an empty string there). Your Order instance is most likely created properly without issues. The variable customer is not a blank value as you say, it's just that when you print it it's string representation is an empty string.

Comment: What is `username` field value?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat This hasn't seemed to work unfortunately. It's also blank on the database so I don't believe its just a representational problem (I have on_delete set to null). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @unknown username value prints off correctly too.

Comment: @sthompson232 Can you show `print(customer.username)`?

Comment: @unknown what do you mean sorry? `print(customer.username)` will print off the current user's username like it should normally do.

Comment: @sthompson232 This is strange because the `AbstractUser` inherits from the `AbstractBaseUser`, who already has a `__str__` method that outputs the user's username. Of course, you can try to rewrite the `__str__` method in your model ... But it's very strange.

Comment: Which version of Django you are use?

Comment: @sthompson232 What does `print(order.customer is None)` give you? Also try `print(type(customer))`, also `print(str(customer).strip() == "")`

Comment: @sthompson232 can you show list of all fields of `User` model?

Comment: The User model is already displayed in the question. I only have one extra field added to it!

Comment: django version 3.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now added first_name and last_name to the user and it works. Still a little confused though as I did not set `__str__` or `__repr__` to first or last name on the user model. If anyone knows why this is the case I would be interested to know. Thanks for al the help!